# How to set system time from Unix timestamp

Tags: date, timestamps

I know arbitrary timestamp and I want to set system time using it. I've tried following:

```
date +%s -s "1371729865"
date +%s -s '1371729865'
date +%s -s 1371729865
```

but without success.

The idea is, that I launch system on remote device without internal RT clock (RaspberryPi), and I need to set system time for logging purposes. I don't need exact time.

On RPi I have access to network, but not to internet and I will be sending the time as packet in my application.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You missed `@` character before unix timestamps, try:

```
date +%s -s @1371729865
```

Comment: +%s isn't necessory.